# Handling WebSocket connections in Rack

Tags: ruby, websocket, rack, faye

The [readme](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) for `faye-websocket-ruby` has the below example. What does the line of code

`p [:close, event.code, event.reason]`

do and what does `p` mean there? Also what does `ws.rack_response` do and why is it necessary?

```
# app.rb
require 'faye/websocket'

App = lambda do |env|
  if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
    ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env)

    ws.on :message do |event|
      ws.send(event.data)
    end

    ws.on :close do |event|
      p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
      ws = nil
    end

    # Return async Rack response
    ws.rack_response

  else
    # Normal HTTP request
    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Hello']]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p()` is an instance method of the `Kernel` class [see here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p). It is used for printing (like `puts` does) but it calls the `inspect` method on the argument. It is useful for debugging because you can see exactly what the value is because with puts the integer 1 will be printed as `"1"` which is not what it is.

Every Rack application must respond to a method called `call` that accepts the environment `env` and returns an array of the form

```
[http_code, headers, body]
```

On the example above you can see that the `App` object is a `lambda` accepting the `env` and returning an array of the aforementioned form. Thus it is a Rack application given that a `lambda` has a method `call`.

The `rack_response` method does nothing more than returning a rack compatible array as you can see [HERE](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby/blob/master/lib/faye/websocket.rb#L84).

More about Rack applications [HERE](http://railscasts.com/episodes/317-rack-app-from-scratch).

Comment: Great! Also what about `ws.rack_response`?